# Typical meal costs on Norwegian Air Shuttle long-haul flights

Tags: airlines, food-and-drink, price

What are typical costs for meal service on [Norwegian Air Shuttle](https://www.norwegian.com/US/) on US-Europe flights?

Meals are [described here](https://www.norwegian.com/uk/travel-info/on-board/food-and-drinks/international-long-haul-flights/), but no pricing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite expensive, by the looks of it, at least on "Lowfare"

[This page](https://www.norwegian.com/uk/booking/booking-information/optional-charges/) shows GBP 25 per person and 3-4 GBP for non-alcoholic drinks.

I guess to be sure you can create an account and try to order.